# Excel Macro to Replace last four digits if containing specific number

Tags: excel, digits, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 2000 rows.  My concern is with column B which contains 17 digit numbers.  I'd like to have a macro check all numbers in column B and if the last four digits = "0000" I'd like to change the last four digits to "0001", also if the last four digits = "1900" I'd like to change the last four digits to "1998".  Any other scenario can be skipped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
=LEFT(B1,13)&IF(RIGHT(B1,4)="0000","0001",IF(RIGHT(B1,4)="1900","1998",RIGHT(B1,4)))
```

Just place this in another column and afterwards replace column B with the values from this column.

Comment: It should be "1998" instead of "1988". Secondly, your solution works only for 17 digit number. If digits are less or more, it fails.

Comment: I quote: "My concern is with column B which contains 17 digit numbers"

Comment: I am just sayin casually, if requirement changes in future, it will fail.

Comment: @PareshJadhav: also quoting: "Any other scenario can be skipped." You are right that it would fail, but 1) we can't plan for every unknown scenario and 2) the OP seems pretty clear about the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula for the same. Following is the excel formula for the same:

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2,4)="0000",CONCATENATE(MID(B2,1,LEN(B2)-4),"0001"),IF(RIGHT(B2,4)="1900",CONCATENATE(MID(B2,1,LEN(B2)-4),"1998"),B2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
=IF(RIGHT(B1,4)="0000",B1+1,IF(RIGHT(B1,4)="1900",B1+98,B1))
```